# Disable a commandButton from receiving the "Enter" key

Tags: jsf, form-submit

In the form I am creating, I have lots of buttons that depending on the data state, are disabled or enabled.

I have an issue where, in certain situations, my "Reset Form" button is the only enabled button left on the screen, so it accepts the "enter" keypress... and blows away all the user information.

I need to retain usage of the enter key with the other fields, but I'd like to hide this reset button from ever being seen on the page DOM as the "firstnext" button to invoke on enter keypress.

I've seen a few solutions w/ javascript, but I was hoping there was a native JSF way to do this, or even with an extension library.  Taborder was of no help... Best I could come up with that works is a hidden button on the page dom in front of the reset button that dev/null's.  There's gotta be some sort of cleaner solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, if you declare a button as type="reset" it prevents firstnext recognition.   You can still have an action="#{bean.resetFields}" method being called and it will give you the best of both worlds.